# Validate schema after a database migration

Tags: database-migration, fluent-migrator

Does anyone have a good solution for the following (potential) situation ?

Using a database migration tool such as fluentmigrator we add a migration that in and of itself is perfectly valid, but breaks some other database artifact in a way that won't be discovered until run time. For example removing a column that is referenced in the body of an existing stored proc.

I need to be able to validate the resulting schema in its entirety after a migration, what's the best and most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally it would be nice to have automated tests to verify your database objects, however this may not be achievable.

If you are looking for a way to recompile your objects (stored procedures, views, functions) a simple solution would be to create a migration profile with the sole purpose or dropping and recreating each of these objects.

This wouldn't detect semantic errors in your objects as a result of the migrations, but it would tell you if you've changed or dropped a column that causes compilation errors in dependent objects.

This profile could be executed on an ad hoc basis or as part of your continuous integration and deployment process.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Fluent Migrator has been a great for our project!